# LdapRepository update spring-ldap

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap

Spring LdapRepository save() method throws exception when I'm trying to update an existing object in LDAP database.

```
org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapEntryAlreadyExistsException: ERR_250_ENTRY_ALREADY_EXISTS
```

What method should I use to update existing ldap objects?

Person class:

```
@Entry(objectClasses = { "inetOrgPerson", "organizationalPerson", "person", "top" })
public class Person implements Serializable {

public Person() {
}

@Id
private Name dn;

@Attribute(name = "cn")
@DnAttribute(value = "cn")
@JsonProperty("cn")
private String fullName;

@Attribute(name = "uid")
private String uid;

private String mail;

@Attribute(name = "sn")
private String surname;
//setters and getters
}
```

Person repo interface:

```
public interface PersonRepo extends LdapRepository<Person> {
}
```

That's how I'm updating person:

```
personRepo.save(person);
```

Comment: Please provide code to help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @marthursson, updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default implementation for Spring LDAP repositories is [SimpleLdapRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/ldap/repository/support/SimpleLdapRepository.java), that checks the property annotated with `@Id` to determine if the objects is *new* - and perform create, or *old* - and perform update.

I'm guessing that `Person.dn` is `null` when you're trying to perform update.

You also can take the control over this by implementing `org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable` and place your logic in the `isNew()` method.

See the [implementation details](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/ldap/repository/support/SimpleLdapRepository.java#L73-L94).